# How to stop a program execution with "throw" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, exception, try-catch, throw

I'm resuming javascript studies now and I came across a problem. I have a Customer class that receives customer data in the constructor and validates it before assigning it to its respective properties. When the phone number is incorrect, an exception is thrown which in turn must stop the execution of the entire program, however, this is the problem. I'm throwing the exception and treating it with try/catch but the program continues anyway, here's the code:

```
// Customer class

import { Library } from './Library.js';
import { books } from './books.js';
import chalk from 'chalk';

export class Customer {
    #name;
    #birthdate;
    #email;
    #phone;
    #code;

    constructor(name, birthdate, email, phone) {
        this.#name = name;
        this.#birthdate = birthdate;
        this.#email = email;
        this.#phone = this.#validatePhone(phone);
        this.rented = [];
        this.#code = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 99999); // MUST BE READABLE, ONLY!
    }

    get name() {
        return this.#name;
    }

    get birthdate() {
        return this.#birthdate;
    }

    get email() {
        return this.#email;
    }

    get phone() {
        return this.#phone;
    }

    set name(name) {
        this.#name = name;
    }

    set birthdate(birthdate) {
        this.#birthdate = birthdate;
    }

    set email(email) {
        this.#email = email;
    }

    set phone(phone) {
        this.#phone = phone;
    }

    async rentBoook(title, days) {
        const search = await Library.searchBook(title);
        if(search.length === 0) throw 'This book doesn\'t exist!';

        return await Library.rentBook('O Ar', this, days);
    }

    #validatePhone(phone) {
        try {
            const pattern = /(\(?[0-9]{2}\)?)\s?([0-9]{5})-?([0-9]{4})/;
            if(!pattern.test(phone)) throw 'Invalid phone number!';

            return phone;
        }catch(err) {
            console.log(chalk.red(err));
        }

    }
}
```

```
   // Index

    import chalk from 'chalk';
    import { Customer } from './Customer.js';

    const customer = new Customer('John Doe', '20-04-04', 'r@r.com', '(99) 9999-99999');

    customer.rentBoook('O Ar', 7)
    .then(r => console.log(chalk.green('Book rented with success!')))
    .catch(err => console.log(chalk.red(err)));
```

```
    // Output

    "Invalid phone number!"
    "Book rented with success!"
```

Comment: Due to the fact that you are treating that exception with try/catch results in your program not crashing/ending. Only uncaught exception will result in a crashing program. Or you have to manually exit the program in the catch block.

Answer (score 0):

**Phone validation** should be handled in **rentBook** method, as validation didn't handled inside the rentBook & happened for #phone prop assignment (#phone will become **undefined**), both the method execute independent of one another.

For this case, will get expected result, when validation done inside **rentBook** before **Library.search**

```
async rentBoook(title, days) {
       ....
       validatePhone()
       ...
}
```

remove try catch in validatePhone Method & use try..catch in rentBook if needed

Hope this helps